# Disassembly in Emacs

Tags: emacs, disassembly, ida

How can I disassemble a `.dll` / `.so` (C++/C) or `.pyc` (Python) file in Emacs, as with tools such IDA Pro?

If possible, please share some disassembly snippets/plugins for Emacs.

Maybe Emacs can handle disassembly better than IDA Pro.